# How to stop UIwebview from refreshing?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have made an app that contains a lot of PDF files that are loaded in the UIwebview. Whenever I open the PDF, close it, and then go back to it, the file starts from the top again, it reloads. I don't want it to reload once the user goes out of the file and comes back to it.
can someone help with the code for it to stop refreshing and where i should insert it?

Example of my code is below.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad

    {


    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"HnonC" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [Webview loadRequest:request];
    [Webview setScalesPageToFit:YES];


        [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should cache the URLs, so no URL is requested again.

Creating a URL request, you supply the cache policy:

```
NSURLRequest * req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:@"" cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:10.0f];
[myWebView loadRequest:req];
```